# Need One-way sync between SQL Server and SQL Server Compact in C#.Net

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2, microsoft-sync-framework

Here are 2 databases, one on  SQL Server and the other on  SQL Server Compact.

They have the following rows:

```
SQL Server     SQL Server CE

Id  Name       Id  Name
1   A          1    A
2   B          2    B
3   C          3    C
```

I need a one-way sync. When sync process work then all data of SQL Server Compact sync with  SQL Server (it is the main server).

Now if user deletes data from SQL Server Compact (like delete where id=3) and Sync again.

```
SQL Server     SQL Server CE

Id  Name       Id  Name
1   A          1    A
2   B          2    B
3   C
```

i mean data should not delete from SQL Server.

If user adds data in the SQL Server Compact database and syncs again then newly added data should go to  SQL Server like ....

```
SQL Server     SQL Server CE

Id  Name       Id  Name
1   A          1    A
2   B          2    B
3   C          4    D
4   D
```

Its my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

intercept the change dataset from SQL Ce in the ChangesSelected event of the SQL Ce provider, then remove the delete from the dataset so it doesn't go thru and get applied on the server.

see approach here: http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/manipulating-the-change-dataset-in-sync-fx/